# Regex expression only catching last few values

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex

I have a large document with

```
 <title>words words </title>
```

as descriptors I am trying to find a regex expression to give me the data between those tags I have found this

```
<title.*?>(\w+)</title>
```

which will work but only picks up a few matches I think its because the tags are usually  something like this

```
adaddad<title>Word word word</title>sdfdsfdsfs
```

just has random garbage on both sides usually. I am really bad at regex and still trying to learn it I have found alot of really close post but nothing that works for my problem exactly.

```
:origLink></item>\r\n<item><title>words word word</title><guid is
```

this is a better example of what one of my strings looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your regex greedy

```
 <title.*?>.+?</title>
```

Also, \w+ will not match spaces " "

Try expresso to fine tune your regex http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: Glad to help, Please mark this as the answer so others can quickly find the answer also.

Comment: @Jras, `.+?` is not greedy, it's lazy and you don't have any capturing groups...?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use `\w` to capture text with word characters and whitespace as well. It should be:

```
<title.*?>([\w\s]+?)</title>
```

This will force text like this

```
adaddad<title>Word word word</title>sdfdsfdsfs
```

to be captured with the words and the spaces as well

Answer (score -1):

Use instead

```
^[^<]*<title.*?>([^<]*)</title>.*$
```

Explanation

```
^ at the beginning means begining of line
[^<] any character but '<'
.*$ any garbage after the tag is closed
```

this will catch empty titles as well as any bizarre string you might have in between tags.

```
<title>Normal title</title>
<title></title>
<title>Weird #@!@#%@%^[]{}""///? title ≥╙♥</title>
```